# Any chance of making this faster? (numpy.einsum)

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to multiply three arrays (A x B x A), with the dimensions (19000, 3) x (19000, 3, 3) x (19000, 3) so that at the end I'm getting a 1d-array with the size (19000), so I want to multiply only along the last one/two dimensions.

I've got it working with np.einsum() but I'm wondering if there is any way of making this faster, as this is the bottleneck of my whole code.

`np.einsum('...i,...ij,...j', A, B, A)`

I've already tried it with two separated np.einsum() calls, but that gave me the same performance:

`np.einsum('...i, ...i', np.einsum('...i,...ij', A, B), A)`

As well I've already tried the @ operator and adding some additional axes, but that also didn't make it faster:

`(A[:, None]@B@A[...,None]).squeeze()`

I've tried to get it working with np.inner(), np.dot(), np.tensordot() and np.vdot(), but these never gave me the same results, so I couldn't compare them.

Any other ideas? Is there any way I could get a better performance?

I've already had a quick look at Numba, but as Numba doesn't support np.einsum() and many other NumPy functions, I would have to rewrite a lot of code.

Comment: Can you try setting `optimize=True` in `np.einsum`?

Comment: I've already tried that. But unfortunately  no performance changes at all.

Comment: If this function is your main bottleneck it is enough to just write the einsum expression in Numba. (already tried it -> about 10 times faster with parallelization than the einsum with optimize=True)

Comment: @max9111 As I'm an absolute beginner in Numba: How would I do this? Putting the rewritten np.einsum expression into an extra function and then adding a Numba decorator to it?

Comment: Have you tried opt_einsum ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### You could use Numba

In the beginning it is always a good idea, to look what np.einsum does. With `optimize==optimal` it is usually really good to find a way of contraction, which has less FLOPs. In this case there is actually only a minor optimization possible and the intermediate array is relatively large (I will stick to the naive version). It should also be mentioned that contractions with very small (fixed?) dimensions are a quite special case. This is also a reason why it is quite easy to outperfom `np.einsum` here (unrolling etc..., which a compiler does if it knows that a loop consists only of 3 elements)

```
import numpy as np

A=np.random.rand(19000, 3)
B=np.random.rand(19000, 3, 3)

print(np.einsum_path('...i,...ij,...j', A, B, A,optimize="optimal")[1])

"""
  Complete contraction:  si,sij,sj->s
         Naive scaling:  3
     Optimized scaling:  3
      Naive FLOP count:  5.130e+05
  Optimized FLOP count:  4.560e+05
   Theoretical speedup:  1.125
  Largest intermediate:  5.700e+04 elements
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
scaling                  current                                remaining
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
   3                  sij,si->js                                 sj,js->s
   2                    js,sj->s                                     s->s

"""
```

**Numba implementation**

```
import numba as nb

#si,sij,sj->s
@nb.njit(fastmath=True,parallel=True,cache=True)
def nb_einsum(A,B):
    #check the input's at the beginning
    #I assume that the asserted shapes are always constant
    #This makes it easier for the compiler to optimize 
    assert A.shape[1]==3
    assert B.shape[1]==3
    assert B.shape[2]==3

    #allocate output
    res=np.empty(A.shape[0],dtype=A.dtype)

    for s in nb.prange(A.shape[0]):
        #Using a syntax like that is also important for performance
        acc=0
        for i in range(3):
            for j in range(3):
                acc+=A[s,i]*B[s,i,j]*A[s,j]
        res[s]=acc
    return res
```

**Timings**

```
#warmup the first call is always slower 
#(due to compilation or loading the cached function)
res=nb_einsum(A,B)
%timeit nb_einsum(A,B)
#43.2 µs ± 1.22 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
%timeit np.einsum('...i,...ij,...j', A, B, A,optimize=True)
#450 µs ± 8.28 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
%timeit np.einsum('...i,...ij,...j', A, B, A)
#977 µs ± 4.14 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
np.allclose(np.einsum('...i,...ij,...j', A, B, A,optimize=True),nb_einsum(A,B))
#True
```

Comment: Ok, seems like I was completely wrong. The real bottleneck wasn't np.einsum but my array B, which in reality is the inverse of another array, let's call it C.

So the actual case was:
np.einsum('...i,...ij,...j', A, inv(C), A)
And the calculation of the inverse was the real bottleneck here!

After googling quite a lot I found out, that I don't even need the inverse and could instead just use np.solve(C, A).

So in the end my implementation is:

np.einsum('...i,...i', A, np.linalg.solve(C, A))

which gives me a speed up of around 30x!